# A utilização da função handler esta pulando os ids. Como faço para isso não acontecer?

Tags: mysql, handler

Veja o exemplo:

```
create table time(
id int not null primary key auto_increment,
nome varchar(50) unique
)engine=innodb;

delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE insertteam (nometime varchar(50))
begin
declare continue handler for 1062
select 'vc ja inseriu esse nome anteriormente';
insert into time (id, nome)
values(null, nometime);
end$$
delimiter ;

call insertteam ('BRASIL');
select * from time;
```

Se eu "chamar" e inserir *brasil* novamente ele trava corretamente, até ai tudo ok. Mas quando vou inserir um time que ainda não existe ele insere corretamente, mas pula os ids nas respectivas vezes que tentei inserir brasil novamente e deu errado.

Por exemplo: se eu tentar inserir brasil 5 vezes ele insere a primeira e da erro nas outras. Mas depois quando eu for inserir "mexico" ele insere corretamente mas no id = 6.

Comment: No SO.en existe uma pergunta parecida: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16582704/540552

Answer (score 0):

Quando acontece um erro ao tentar inserir o MySQL queima o id e seta o autoincrement +1 você pode verificar se possui erro na execução e setar o autoincrement alterando a tabela, porém não acho viável, creio que verificando qual o próximo valor a ser inserido antes de realizar o insert é mais viavél:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS inseretime;
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE inseretime(nometime VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN

    DECLARE error INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE v_autoincrement INT;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1062 SET error = 1;

    SET @@autocommit = 0;

    START TRANSACTION;

        SELECT 
                MAX(id) + 1
        INTO v_autoincrement
        FROM time;
        INSERT INTO time VALUES(v_autoincrement, nometime);

        IF error = 1 THEN

            SELECT 'vc ja inseriu esse nome anteriormente';
            ROLLBACK;
            /** CASO QUEIRA ALTERAR O AUTO_INCREMENT DA TABELA **/
            -- ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = v_autoincrement;


        ELSE

            COMMIT;

        END IF;

END
|
DELIMITER ;
```